# Android TV app is Live but review has failed for TV devices in Catalog

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services

I have the issue wherein the app is live, but TV devices have failed review. There is no Email from Google as well. All the google policies have been adhered to. The app is live on mobile and also the TV build is accepted but in the device catalog, it shows a review failed but there is no specific reason mentioned. I have been stuck on this issue for a while now, I tried submitting new builds thinking it might be a glitch on Google's side but no success. PS: Leanback is set to True and touchscreen is set to False. Does anyone know the way ahead?